# Don't understand my mounted partitions

Tags: linux

[image]

I plugged a samsung phone in my ubuntu pc, and it didn't want to mount automatically.
So, i had a look in fdisk, i found it, but by typing df -h, i found all those lines...
I have removed anbox, but can you explin me please those lines and if i can remove them (i thonk from /etc/fstab).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for contributing! But please, don't post images of text ([read this for reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)).

Comment: Is the fact that you have plugged your phone into your computer at all relevant to the question?

Comment: Yes, say "i discovered" those mounted points when i typed df -h....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

udisks2 is likely the utility which is auto-mounting your removable storage devices. There's Ubuntu [documentation](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/disk/udisks2/docs/reference/snap-configuration/automount) about how it works, and how to disable it if you'd like.

As for the mounted filesystems, in short, that's how linux works. Here's an overview of the filesystems you have mounted:

- `/dev` - This is a [pseudo-filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_file_system) which presents [device files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#BLOCKDEV).
- `/run` - This is an in-memory (RAM) filesystem used for temporary files used during runtime.
- `/` - This is your root filesystem.
- `/snap/*` - These are filesystem image files being mounted via [loop devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device), which in your case are being used to mount filesystems containing various Snap programs.
- `/run/cgmanager` - cgmanager is used to manage Linux cgroups (control groups), typically for containers.

While it may be possible to remove some of those filesystems, unless you know precisely what you are doing, I recommend leaving them as-is. Otherwise you may accidently cause some of your programs to stop working.

Comment: thank you.You're right, i use docker and other services you mentionned.